# Grouping Start Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

Example of what I am trying to do:

I have 10 employees. They all started on different days throughout the year. Each get paid once a week. I want to query their first paycheck and call that week 1 for all employees. Then each subsequent paycheck will be 2...3...through 13. So basically I want to see what each of their first 13 weeks on the job looked like stacked against each other. I would expect my output to look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select
    row_number() over(partition by EmployeeId order by PaycheckDate) week,
    EmployeeId,
    PaycheckDate,
    Amount
from mytable
order by week, EmployeeId
```

If you want just the first 13 weeks per employee, then:

```
select *
from (
    select
        row_number() over(partition by EmployeeId order by PaycheckDate) week,
        EmployeeId,
        PaycheckDate,
        Amount
    from mytable
) t
where week <= 13
order by week, EmployeeId
```

Comment: @Glock . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  I would strongly encourage you to accept this answer and as a NEW question.  Stack Overflow is not a forum for dialogs.  It is a question-and-answer site.